# How to rearrange and append data contained in a column of a df in the rows of another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have big difficulties in moving data from a dataframe to a new empty one.

These are my dfs

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

I would like to rearrange the values of df1['Close'] in df2['Close','Close 2','Close 3',...,'Close n']  putting in one row let's say 20 'Close' values of df1 (df1 20 first rows), in one row of df2, and proceed with the second row of df2 putting next 20 rows of df1(from 21 to 40). This will happend while ignoring the target columns of both dfs, so I have tried with these parameters as example.
I try to explain better.. 5 (inside the range of the for loop) is the numbers of rows in which I would like to dispose the first 100 values from df1['Close'] in df2:

```
for j in range (0, 5):

    count = 20;
    amazon_df_copy = 
amazon_df_copy.iloc[j:j+1,1:len(amazon_df_copy.columns)].append(normalized_amazon_df.iloc[:count,1:2]);
    count += 20;
```

The result is this:

[image]

I have tried even in different ways but I could achieve to fill only one column, and in the result the order of my columns is changing and even some of them are missing. When I am done I will delete the NaN remaining values, while the targets will be filled with the one corresponding to the 20 inputs (the close columns, but that's not important now).

I hope it's understandable what I would like to achieve and I hope you can help. :(

Comment: @ShivamRoy thank you so much!! I would like to insert Target values this way from df1 to df2:
df1['Target][1] --> df2['Target'][1]
df1['Target][21] --> df2['Target'][2]
df1['Target][41] --> df2['Target'][3]
 and so on..

Comment: Hi @Alexander Gechev, I would request you to comment on my answer as I do not get any notifications when you comment on your own question. And about the `Target` values, I'm really sorry but I'm not sure I have still understood it. Do you want to have the `Target` rows in a similar manner to the `Close` rows? Or do you only want the 1st, 21'st, 41th, and so on values?

Comment: I think I have understood your requirement, I have edited my answer. Please let me know if it works for you and if my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by taking the transpose of every 20 columns using [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) likewise:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df1.Close.values.reshape(-1, 20), 
                columns= ['Close'] + ['Close' + str(i) for i in range(1,20)])
```

If I understood the requirement for the `Target` column in your comment correctly, you want to store every 20th value including the 1st-row value in the `Target` column of df1 into the new_df  You can use `iloc` for the same:

```
new_df['Target'] = df1.iloc[::20].tolist()
```

Comment: yes, your assumption was correct, I have tried to use your code but I am receiving this error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12246 into shape (20).
I am trying to solve the problem by understanting the reshape and the sintax, unfortunately I am not confident with python, but if I won't find a solution, I'll write you back. In the meantime thank you for your kindness!

Comment: @AlexanderGechev I'll tell you the reason, its because when you use `reshape(-1, 20)`, it implies that we want to reshape our DataFrame into a 2D array with the number of columns as 20 and the number of rows is deduced by the method by dividing the value 12246 in your case by 20. Since 12246 is not a multiple of 20, you'll get this error. You'll have to either add 14 dummy rows or delete 6 rows to make it a multiple of 20.

Comment: I did it!


`new_df_targets = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Target']);
new_df_targets['Target'] = normalized_amazon_df['Target'].iloc[::39];

new_df_close = pd.DataFrame(normalized_amazon_df['Close'].values.reshape(-1, 39), 
        columns= ['Close'] + ['Close' + str(i) for i in range(1,39)]).reset_index(drop=True);

new_df = pd.concat((new_df_targets, new_df_close), axis=1);`

For the tests I wanted to do this is enough, but eventually it's good to consider the creation of dummies. Thank you very much for your patience, despite my bad english you were really kind to me

Comment: @AlexanderGechev No problem at all. I'm really glad my answer could help you. And please stop worrying about your English, it is good enough. :)  I would be really grateful if you could mark the answer as "Accepted" if it helped you. Thanks :)